# How to use Java 9 Flow Interfaces / what's the point of including them in Java 9?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, java-9

First I have to say that I have not much experience with Reactive Programming.

Since there are only a few interfaces in JDK 9 ([Flow and its nested interfaces](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html)), JDK 9 obviously does not include a reactive library like RxJava.

In the Javadoc, there are some examples for implentations of `Publisher`, `Subscription`, and `Subscriber`. But these seem to be quite low-level and do not have any reactive operators or handling of back-pressure.

So what is the point of including those interfaces into the JDK?

Are vendors of reactive libraries supposed to use them, so that Java implementations (like RxJava) of those use a common set of interfaces? (similar to JPA and Hibernate?)

Comment: In addition, does Java 9 support rx-java observable methods? Is Java 9 gave only the infrastructure to rx-java?

Comment: Have you done prior research - like reading the corresponding jep?

Comment: Just to add to what @GhostCat pointed, do take a look at [JEP#266](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/266).

Comment: @GhostCat: well I have searched, but as this question is like "What's new in Java 9" then for Rx experts, I thought JEPs may not be acessible for someone with limited exposure to Rx. Anyway, something like an answer is in https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Reactive-Streams but I am not sure if I am competent enough for adding an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It mainly allows Java itself to use reactive programming internally in some future version, such as Reactive JDBC, Networking, IO, etc. In concept, it also serves as a new rally point for interoperation, however, such rally point already exists with Reactive Streams targeting a much larger audience via its Java 6 requirement.

As you mentioned, having that 4 interfaces and the `SubmissionPublisher` by itself has limited use. If Java had extension methods similar to Kotlin and C#, the inclusion of the interfaces could have much more interesting impact.

Unfortunately, it also means that existing libraries have to use bridges to convert between Java 9 Flow and Reactive-Streams and/or reimplement the whole library with Java 9 Flow API - cutting out anybody without Java 9 (i.e., Android).

Major libraries have already such bridges ([RxJava 2 Jdk 9 Interop](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Jdk9Interop#rxjava2jdk9interop), [Reactor-Core Interop](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/adapter/JdkFlowAdapter.java)) and the Reactive-Streams will have its [own bridge eventually](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/pull/296). There is also a [prototype reactive library](https://github.com/akarnokd/Reactive4JavaFlow#reactive4javaflow) written for and with Java 9 features.

Comment: Just to add to this impressive list, there *exists* a Flow backport for Android: [streamsupport-flow](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/)

Answer (score 2):

The aim of flow interface is to provide "a standard for asynchronous stream processing with non-blocking back pressure". There are already a lot of solutions that achieve that (like Rx), but by introducing a common interface it maximizes interoperability.

the back pressure is the key point, back pressure being, that if the producer gives a callback, the consumer can call that callback at a rate faster than what the producer can handle.

It is easy to achiever BLOCKING back pressure by running them on the same thread so that the consumer and producer block each other.

This Flow interface will allow us to achieve NON BLOCKING back pressure.

The details of which are explained in more detail in this link (and also information on how to use the interface): https://aboullaite.me/java-9-new-features-reactive-streams/